# Error retrieving data in Excel

Tags: web-services, excel, iis, vba

I have a ASP.NET web application, when I click menu "report", it will download an microsoft office excel template from server, and when the excel file opened, there is an "retrieve data" button, by clicking this button, excel with vba script will download the data from webservice.
I'm sure nothing wrong about vba script on excel template.

Now, I have development server, let we call it "server A" with Win server 2k3. And also I have a local development environment, with windows xp service pack 2. let we call it "local server B"

when I access my web application on server A from my local PC (local server B), and click "report" button, an excel file will be downloaded. And then I click button "Retrieve data" on excel, an error happen :

[image]
I cannot retrieve data from server.

But if I use remote desktop, and connect to server A, and I access my application (in server A) in browser in server A locally..as I told above, the data was retrieved successfully.

I tried another plan, I try to access my application in local server (local server B) from a web broser in server A, and data was retrieved successfully.

Any idea about the fvcking error ? is it about IIS configuration ?
I need your helps, guys,
thanks,

regards,

Comment: It may be worth posting this on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like network connectivity / routing issues.  Can your computer access `10.3.3.52`?  If this is not a public IP, then you need to be on the same LAN as the destination server, and any firewalls in place need to allow the traffic.

Comment: thanks for your reply, hhmm...I think so, buat, how can if I accesss my application from server A to my local sever, it running well ?